# PHP extending MySQL master class TWICE

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Below is the solution to my question. I didn't have my class written wrong. I accidentally used a "die" function inside my master DB class that made all my queries fail. I was tracking down the wrong problem.

I hope you guys find this class example useful. It's clean, and very useful for wrapping SQL calls in a single location for multiple databases. By allowing the extension, you can track your calls much easier my var name.

```
class A extends DB {

    protected $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host      = "server.com:3327";
        $this->db_name      = "db_name_one";
        $this->db_username  = "root";
        $this->db_password  = 'pw';

        // .. equals all the setup vars
        parent::__construct();
    }   

}

class B extends DB {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host      = "server.com:3327";
        $this->db_name      = "db_name_two";
        $this->db_username  = "root";
        $this->db_password  = 'pw';

        // .. equals all the setup vars
        parent::__construct();
    }   

}

class DB {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect()
    }
    public function connect()
        if (!$connection = @ mysql_connect ($this->db_host,$this->db_username,$this->db_password,$this->second_flag))
            die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());

        if (!mysql_selectdb($this->db_name,$connection))
            $this->showerror();

        return $connection;
    }   
    public function executeSQL($query)
    {
        $results =  mysql_query($query,$this->connection); 

        if (!$results) {
            die(...);
        }

        return $results;
    }
}

$db1 = new A();
$db2 = new B();

$db1->executeSQL("select * from table");
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. Can you post a minimal example, showing where the error happens?

Comment: `mysql_connect` returns a resource which you can feed into all other `mysql_*` functions. That's how you can have multiple connections at once; you just need to keep track of that resource. As it is, there's little beyond this that we could tell you because your questions contains no code and is too abstract to answer.

Comment: Added pseudo code. Assume the sub classes are creating and using the __construct properly.

Comment: 1) You cannot return anything from a constructor. 2) Why do you have two identical sub classes? – Overall it sounds like you simply don't know how to design a class or object.

Comment: So much for your RIGHT brain. It's PSEUDO code. I'll clean it up so I can get help.

Comment: That was a little too real to be pseudo... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a legitimate reason to extend the `DB` class here. Unless those extending classes *add* something to the `DB` (e.g. they adapt it to a different database), then they have nothing to do with being a `DB` as such. Just because they *use* a `DB` doesn't mean they should `extend` one.

The simplest thing to do is: make one class that handles your database interaction. When you make a new instance of that class, it establishes a new connection to the database. This way you can have as many independent connections as you want. You then simply pass those instances to whoever needs them:

```
class DB {

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(..);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            throw new Exception(..);
        }
    }

    ..

}


class A {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(DB $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    ..

}


$db = new DB;
$a  = new A($db);
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have elaborated a bit. I use the helper class to do the sql specific calls. I wrap every single call type. This allows me to hot swap the mysql_ with mysqli_ and any other connection methods that show up. I also handle all my debugging in the central class. This just eliminates the need to duplicate everything. I'm going to try a few things and report back.

Comment: Right, that's what your `DB` class should be for. It abstracts the `mysql_` calls, you can swap those out for anything else you like. Ideally you'd use an `interface` or abstract class to define all the possible database calls you want to make from your app, then implement that in a concrete class for `mysql_` or whatever else you like.

Comment: I found my problem. I've corrected the classes above with my original question, which had nothing to do with my problem.